# Распределенный Erlang

Tags: erlang

Возникла необходимость сделать распределенное приложение на Erlang'е.
Добавил {global, ?MODULE} и при запуске приложения появилась ошибка

```
{error,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,feed_a,
                              {undef,[{global,init,
                                        [[feed_a,86364999],{global,source_server}],
                                                         []},
                               {gen_server,init_it,6,  [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,328}]},
                                        {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                                                         [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,240}]}]}}},
         {child,undefined,feed_a,
                {source_server_sup,start_link,[feed_a,86364999]},
                           permanent,5000,supervisor,
                                      [source_server_sup]}}}
```

в чем причина, код https://github.com/Spasennyi4ert/source